# Update password in keychain for touchId without authentication UI

Tags: ios, objective-c, authentication, touch-id, xcode8

In my app when touch ID is enabled I save the username and password in keychain and add it to the available fingerprint added on device. So, user can login to the app with touch from next time onwards. Now when the password is changed, and user tries to login with touch ID it gives an error which is correct, now when the user enters the new password manually I need to update the keychain so that the touch login would work from next time onwards. But the problem is when I call the update method it gives me the touch ID prompt. Is there a way to update it without showing the prompt? Below is my current update method

```
+(BOOL) updatePassword:(NSString *)password{


    NSDictionary *query = @{
                            (id)kSecClass : (id)kSecClassGenericPassword,
                            (id)kSecAttrService : @"passwordService",
                            (id)kSecUseOperationPrompt : NSLocalizedString(@"Update Prompt", @"")
                            };

    NSData *newPassword = [password dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];

    NSDictionary *changes = @{
                              (id)kSecValueData : newPassword
                              };


    OSStatus status = SecItemUpdate((__bridge CFDictionaryRef)query, (__bridge CFDictionaryRef)changes);

    if (status == errSecSuccess) {
        return YES;
    }
    else{
        return NO;
    }
}
```

Comment: Would you consider a solution calling `SecItemDelete` and then `SecItemAdd`?

Comment: @Mats, that is my last resort, if this doesn't work.

Comment: Im having this same issue, would like to avoid calling `SecItemDelete` then `SecItemAdd`, have you found anything more a bout this? Thanks

Comment: If I use SecItemDelete, it asks for finger touch, any other solution?